# Compare two different files line by line in python

Tags: python, file

I have two different files and I want to compare theirs contents line by line, and write their common contents in a different file. Note that both of them contain some blank spaces. 
Here is my pseudo code:

```
file1 = open('some_file_1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('some_file_2.txt', 'r')
FO = open('some_output_file.txt', 'w')

for line1 in file1:
    for line2 in file2:
        if line1 == line2:
            FO.write("%s\n" %(line1))

FO.close()
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

However, by doing this, I got lots of blank spaces in my **FO** file. Seems like common blank spaces are also written. I want to write only the text part. Can somebody please help me.

For example: my first file (file1) contains data:

```
Config:
Hostname = TUVALU

BT:
TS_Ball_Update_Threshold = 0.2

BT:
TS_Player_Search_Radius = 4

BT:
Ball_Template_Update = 0
```

while second file (file2) contains data:

```
Pole_ID      = 2
Width        = 1280
Height       = 1024
Color_Mode   = 0
Sensor_Scale = 1

Tracking_ROI_Size = 4
Ball_Template_Update = 0
```

If you notice, last two lines of each files are the same, hence, I want to write this file in my **FO** file. But, the problem with my approach is that, it writes the common blank space also. Should I use regex for this problem? I do not have experience with regex.

Comment: When you say you want to compare them line by line, do you mean you want to check if the line is in both files or in the same location in both files? Can you post example input and output files?

Comment: line should be in both the files (common line).

Comment: Does it need to be in the same location? Like if `test` is in file 1 on line 3, will it match `test` in file 2 on line six?

Comment: @thegrinner I posted an example now. May be now its better.

Comment: @thegrinner location does not matter, as I said. It should be the same text, can be located anywhere in the files.

Comment: Yeah, that clears up my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This solution reads both files in one pass, excludes blank lines, and prints common lines regardless of their position in the file:

```
with open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('some_file_2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Comment: I'm wondering though, how would I keep the different lines only? Great answer by the way!

Comment: @BrettJ, that would be possible with the .difference() or .symmetric_difference() methods using the same approach listed here (just replace the 'intersection' method).

You could also use the difference_update() or symmetric_difference_update() methods to remove all common elements from an existing set, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Created two files with same name some_file_1.txt,some_file_2.txt. Then I executed the above program. But I got zero records in some_output_file.txt. Even though there are records in some_file_1.txt and zero records in some_file_2.txt. Can anyone kindly help.

Comment: This will literally shred the files. You would need something like an ordered multi-set.

Comment: @Teck-freak - can you expand on that? What do you mean by "shred" ?

Comment: @Robᵩ well if you use it, you will loose information if the lines exist multiple times or in which order they come. Might be ok for a config file though. Sorry, stumbled in searching for a way of functionally comparing python scripts after a veeery long day. I didn't notice the "regardles of their position" part. ... +1 as I think this will be the fastest solution as well as the quickest one. I wonder what it would look like in a buffered version...

Answer (score 15):

Yet another example...

```
from __future__ import print_function #Only for Python2

with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        if line1 == line2:
            print(line1, end='', file=outfile)
```

And if you want to eliminate common blank lines, just change the if statement to:

`if line1.strip() and line1 == line2:`

`.strip()` removes all leading and trailing whitespace, so if that's all that's on a line, it will become an empty string `""`, which is considered false.

Answer (score 13):

If you are specifically looking for getting the difference between two files, then this might help:

```
with open('first_file', 'r') as file1:
    with open('second_file', 'r') as file2:
        difference = set(file1).difference(file2)

difference.discard('\n')

with open('diff.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in difference:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Comment: I found that if the first file is smaller than the second, this difference() function doesn't seem to work as expected (returns no difference). I ended up having to check both `file1.difference(file2)` and `file2.difference(file1)`. For a total of four calls: 

`difference = set(file1).difference(set(file2))`
`file1.seek(0)`
`file2.seek(0)`
`difference2 = set(file2).difference(set(file1))`

I have not done a deeper analysis to understand why this is.

Comment: @Thumper try using `symmetric_difference` instead. From doc: `difference: ... Return a new set with elements in the set that are not in the others.` while `symmetric_difference: ... Return a new set with elements in either the set or other but not both.`

Comment: Nice solution using `symmetric_difference`. I tried using it to find out difference/s between two files with lines of codes (with a little difference added to a line of code, for test). **The result gives an output** with both the code lines one after the other (the ones to which I have added some difference). Is **it possible** to kind of `append` the **file names** (i.e. `first_file` and `second_file`) to the respective **code lines** which differ and show in the **output file**?

Answer (score 9):

If order is preserved between files you might also prefer `difflib`. Although Robᵩ's result is the bona-fide standard for intersections you might actually be looking for a rough diff-like:

```
from difflib import Differ

with open('cfg1.txt') as f1, open('cfg2.txt') as f2:
    differ = Differ()

    for line in differ.compare(f1.readlines(), f2.readlines()):
        if line.startswith(" "):
            print(line[2:], end="")
```

That said, this has a different behaviour to what you asked for (order is important) even though in this instance the same output is produced.

Answer (score 4):

Once the file object is iterated, it is exausted.

```
>>> f = open('1.txt', 'w')
>>> f.write('1\n2\n3\n')
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('1.txt', 'r')
>>> for line in f: print line
...
1

2

3

# exausted, another iteration does not produce anything.
>>> for line in f: print line
...
>>>
```

Use [`file.seek`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.seek) (or close/open the file) to rewind the file:

```
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> for line in f: print line
...
1

2

3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

filename1 = "G:\\test1.TXT"
filename2 = "G:\\test2.TXT"


with open(filename1) as f1:
   with open(filename2) as f2:
      file1list = f1.read().splitlines()
      file2list = f2.read().splitlines()
      list1length = len(file1list)
      list2length = len(file2list)
      if list1length == list2length:
          for index in range(len(file1list)):
              if file1list[index] == file2list[index]:
                  print file1list[index] + "==" + file2list[index]
              else:                  
                  print file1list[index] + "!=" + file2list[index]+" Not-Equel"
      else:
          print "difference inthe size of the file and number of lines"
```

Answer (score 1):

`difflib` is well worth the effort, with nice condensed output.

```
from pathlib import Path
import difflib
  
mypath = '/Users/x/lib/python3'
file17c = Path(mypath, 'oop17c.py')
file18c = Path(mypath, 'oop18c.py')

with open(file17c) as file_1:
    file1 = file_1.readlines()
  
with open(file18c) as file_2:
    file2 = file_2.readlines()
  
for line in difflib.unified_diff(
         file1, file2, fromfile=str(file17c), tofile=str(file18c), lineterm=''):
    print(line)
```

output

> + ... unique stuff present in file18c

> - ... stuff absent in file18c but present in file17c

Answer (score 0):

I have just been faced with the same challenge, but I thought "Why programming this in Python if you can solve it with a simple "grep"?, which led to the following Python code:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

try:
  output1, errors1 = subprocess.Popen(["c:\\cygwin\\bin\\grep", "-Fvf" ,"c:\\file1.txt", "c:\\file2.txt"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate();
  output2, errors2 = subprocess.Popen(["c:\\cygwin\\bin\\grep", "-Fvf" ,"c:\\file2.txt", "c:\\file1.txt"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate();
  if (len(output1) + len(output2) + len(errors1) + len(errors2) > 0):
    print ("Compare result : There are differences:");
    if (len(output1) + len(output2) > 0):
      print ("  Output differences : ");
      print (output1);
      print (output2);
    if (len(errors1) + len(errors2) > 0):
      print (" Errors : ");
      print (errors1);
      print (errors2);
  else:
    print ("Compare result : Both files are equal");
except Exception as ex:
  print("Compare result : Exception during comparison");
  print(ex);
  raise;
```

The trick behind this is the following:
`grep -Fvf file1.txt file2.txt` verifies if all entries in file2.txt are present in file1.txt. By doing this in both directions we can see if the content of both files are "equal". I put "equal" between quotes because duplicate lines are disregarded in this way of working.

Obviously, this is just an example: you can replace `grep` by any commandline file comparison tool.

Comment: semicolons ... why?

Comment: I'm also programming in C/C++/C# and Java, hence the habit of the semicolons. They have no meaning in Python programming.

Comment: @Dominique yes, they do: semicolons end a line prematurely, allowing the rest of the line to be read as next line.