# How to find words that are not the same between two text files

Tags: python

I have two text documents,  that contain essentially all of the same words, but there are a few exceptions. How do I find words in document2 that are not anywhere in document1 and print them out? For example:

document1:
"Hello there how are you"

document2:
"Hi how are you today John"

Desired output:
"Hi today John"

Edit: I would like to print the words that are present in document2 only and not found anywhere in document1. I don't want to print the words that are the same between them.

I created this code that I think finds matches between the two text files, which is not really what I want it to do:

```
doc1 = open("K:\System Files\Desktop\document1.txt", "r+")
doc2 = open("K:\System Files\Desktop\document2.txt", "r+")

list1 = []
list2 = []

for i in doc1: #Removes the new line after each word
    i = i[:-1]
    list1.append(i)
for i in doc2:
    i = i[:-1]
    list2.append(i)

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i == j:
            print(i)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two different files line by line in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007383/compare-two-different-files-line-by-line-in-python)

Comment: Document 1 has 138 words and document 2 has 187 -- each word is on a new line because it's a list. I'm new to programming in general so I haven't gotten very far, but I think I was able to create code that prints the words that match between the two files (I'll edit my original post so you can see it). Now I would like to find a way to print the words that exist only in document2 and not anywhere in document1.

Comment: I suggest you add an `r` prefix to your two paths, e.g. `r"K:\System....txt"` to avoid problems with your backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not worried about the order of the words, then you could use sets to accomplish this as follows:

```
import re

def get_words(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_input:
        return set(w.lower() for w in re.findall(r'(\w+)', f_input.read()))

words1 = get_words('document1.txt')
words2 = get_words('document2.txt')

print words2 - words1
```

This would display:

```
set(['john', 'hi', 'today'])
```

Using `-` on two sets has the effect of giving you the [difference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html?highlight=set#set-objects) between the two sets.