# Python: How to compare 2 file text?

Tags: file, python-3.x, compare

I have 1 large file text A and 1 small file text B. Now, I want compare file B and file A to see what is unique in file B.

For example:
File A:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

File B

```
2
3
6
7
```

==> ouput

```
6
7
```

What is best solution for this ? I searched some thread in the website but i think my question is different because my file is large. Thanks 
The below is my code but it doesn't work

```
with open('C:/unique.txt', 'wb') as out:
    for line in open ('C:/B.txt'):
      for line1 in open ( 'C:/A.txt' ):
        if line != line1:
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two different files line by line in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007383/compare-two-different-files-line-by-line-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me. Hope this helps

```
with open('C:/unique.txt,'r+') as text:
    with open('C:/unique2.txt','r+') as text2:
        for read in text.readlines():
            for read2 in text2.readlines():
                if read2 not in read:
                    print(read2)
```