# How to check if the lines in two files are included in each other

Tags: python

I am new to python have got a problem with comparison of two files and get the output in Boolean form. I have seen few recommendations here, but due to less application knowledge I think I couldn't get still. These two permission related text files need to be compared

1ST text file :perm.txt

```
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
BLUETOOTH
CAMERA
CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
GET_ACCOUNTS
GET_TASKS
MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
READ_LOGS
RECORD_AUDIO
SET_WALLPAPER
USE_CREDENTIALS
VIBRATE
WRITE_CALENDAR
```

---

2ND TEXT FILE file :op3.txt

```
GET_TASKS
EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
SET_WALLPAPER
CAMERA
MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
VIBRATE
RECORD_AUDIO
```

I need to compare 2nd file permissions with first file and based on comparison if permission  is same in two files output should be '1' or 'True' if not it should be '0' or 'False'

I tried with the following codes

```
f1 = open('op2.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('permissions.txt', 'r')
FO = open('out1.txt', 'w')

for line1 in sorted(f2):
    if line1 is f1:
        FO.write(line1 + "True" + '\n')
    else:
        FO.write(line1 + "False" + '\n')

FO.close()
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

another attempt i tried like this intially was able to get the output for two or three permissions i tried in diff ways but couldnt get it finally i struck here at this point

```
fname1 = input("Enter the first filename: ")
fname2 = input("Enter the second filename: ")


f1 = open(fname1)
f2 = open(fname2)


print("-----------------------------------")
print("Comparing files ", " > " + fname1, " < " + fname2, sep='\n')
print("-----------------------------------")


f1_line = f1.readline()
f2_line = f2.readline()

line_no = 1

# Loop if either file1 or file2 has not reached EOF
while f1_line != '' or f2_line != '':


f1_line = f1_line.rstrip()
f2_line = f2_line.rstrip()


if f1_line != f2_line:

    # If a line does not exist on file2 then mark the output with false
    if f2_line == '' and f1_line != '':
        print("false", "Line-%d" % line_no, f1_line)
    # otherwise output the line on file1 and mark it with > sign
    elif f1_line != '':
        print("True", "Line-%d" % line_no, f1_line)



    # Print a blank line
    print()

# Read the next line from the file
f1_line = f1.readline()
f2_line = f2.readline()


line_no += 1


f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: What has this to do with Android?

Comment: `set(file1) == set(file2)`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007383/compare-two-different-files-line-by-line-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do this is below:

```
f1 = open('perm.txt', 'rb')
f2 = open('op3.txt', 'rb')
f1_lines = f1.readlines()
f2_lines = f2.readlines()
f1.close()
f2.close()
overall_compare_result = True
fo = open('out1.txt', 'w')
for each in f1_lines:
    if each in f2_lines:
        fo.write(each.strip() + ' True\n')
    else:
        fo.write(each.strip() + ' False\n')
        if overall_compare_result:
            overall_compare_result = False
fo.close()
print("overall comparision result: " + str(overall_compare_result))
```

**out.txt will have below:**

```
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION True
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION True
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE False
BLUETOOTH False
CAMERA True
CHANGE_WIFI_STATE True
EXPAND_STATUS_BAR True
GET_ACCOUNTS False
GET_TASKS True
MANAGE_DOCUMENTS True
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE True
READ_LOGS False
RECORD_AUDIO False
SET_WALLPAPER True
USE_CREDENTIALS False
VIBRATE True
WRITE_CALENDAR False
```

Comment: @muppavaramkireet if this is serving your purpose, can you please accept this as answer and upvote it?

Comment: I must say that this answer is the longest and least efficient of all.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a fast and quick string comparison, why don't you use hashing (md5/sha1)?

Sort the lines, then use something like this:

```
import md5

m1 = md5.md5(file1_str)
m2 = md5.md5(file2_str)

if m1.hexdigest() == m2.hexdigest():
    ....
else:
    ....
```

Comment: I think this is a huge overkill in terms of computational complexity.

Comment: The computational complexity of MD5 is O(N), so I'm not sure it is a "huge" overkill.

Comment: Well, "Sort the lines" is superlinear, and md5 is linear with high constants. I also don't think it's really shorter or easier than using sets. Didn't downvote it, though, as it's a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
get_line_set = lambda f_name: set([l.strip() for l in open(f_name, 'r')])
```

Creates a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) of the lines of `f_name`.

Now you can just use

```
get_line_set('perm.txt') == get_line_set('op3.txt')
```

Moreover, sets allow you to see intersection, difference, symmetric difference, and so forth. E.g., to see the difference from `perm.txt` to `op3.txt`, just change this to

```
get_line_set('perm.txt').difference(get_line_set('op3.txt'))
```