# Python : Compare two text-files - Search in text-file

Tags: python, text-files

I have to compare two huge text-files, with the same structure but the values are different.Layout of the files is somewhat like this

```
File 1 :

Name : ABCD
Insurance Comapmy : Comp1 
Spouse : BCDF
Doctor : Dr AB
Membership No : 123456
Amount : 1234
Insurance Claimed : Y


Name : ABCE
Insurance Comapmy : Comp2 
Spouse : BCDE
Doctor : Dr AB
Membership No : 123457
Amount : 123
Insurance Claimed : N

Name : ABCF
Insurance Comapmy : Comp1 
Spouse : BCDG
Doctor : Dr AC
Membership No : 123458
Amount : 12345
Insurance Claimed : Y

..... and so on


File 2 :

Name : ABCD
Insurance Comapmy : Comp1 
Spouse : BCDF
Doctor : Dr AB
Membership No : 123456
Amount : 1224
Insurance Claimed : Y


Name : ABCE
Insurance Comapmy : Comp2 
Spouse : BCDE
Doctor : Dr AB
Membership No : 123457
Amount : 123
Insurance Claimed : N

Name : ABCF
Insurance Comapmy : Comp1 
Spouse : BCDG
Doctor : Dr AB
Membership No : 123458
Amount : 12345
Insurance Claimed : Y

..... and so on
```

Now I have to compare the two files and write the output in third file

If the records match then I have to skip, if it differs then I have to write the record in next file in below format.

```
File 3 :

Membership No : 123456
>Amount : 1234
<Amount : 1224

Membership No : 123458
>Doctor : Dr AC
<Doctor : Dr AB
```

The comparison is working fine and it is displaying all the differences.

Issue is to display Membership No.

I am storing the membership no and displaying the latest one. But if the difference occurs if the latest membership no is not fetched, then it is displaying the wrong membership no.

Like in 1st case, difference occur after membership no, in amount field. So we have the latest membership no. and it get displayed.

But in 2nd case, difference occur before the new membership no, in doctor field. So we have not fetched the latest membership no and it is displaying the old one.

I am fetching the membership no. like this and storing it in a list :

```
if "Membership No :" in f1_line:
        if f1_line not in out:
            out.append(f1_line.split(" Membership No : "))
```

out is the list for all the membership no.

I thought to search the next membership no and store it whenever the "Name" field comes. But I am not able to succeed in this through "mmap".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two different files line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007383/compare-two-different-files-line-by-line-in-python)

Comment: try to write parser from text to python objects (like `dict`s in your case), then compare them