# How do I compare two text files in Django?

Tags: python, django, web

I'm building an online judge system in Django like the one we used to have in Kickstart earlier.

They gave you a text file, `input.txt` and then you got an output after you ran that in the form of an `output.txt` file.

I'm aware of how this is done in Python but I'm not sure how to implement it in a Django application.

**My partial understanding :**

The user submits the `output.txt` file to the form and then we need to implement the Python function in the `views.py` using the `form_class` parameter. ( since I'm using CBVs ).

But the point is that I'm not able to figure out how would the `FormView` ( or the `UpdateView` ) class-based view apply that function to the uploaded file.

**Tl;dr:**  How do I implement a Python function in Django that compares two text files and return if they are the same?

*P.S I'm not including a compiler to the online judge since I'm in the early stages of this app and it might be an overhead expense.*

EDIT : SOLVED

Comment: In method form_valid, you write a file, compare it, and generate a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to create a form for the two text files which uploads them (look at this project for more information: https://github.com/axelpale/minimal-django-file-upload-example). This creates a post request with your files. Then, in your view, you can get the files by accessing the post request data (`request.FILES['file1']`). You can then run a python function on these files. This function should be your comparison function.

See this post for help with a python comparison function: [Compare two different files line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007383/compare-two-different-files-line-by-line-in-python) .

Here is a sample function for what I am talking about:

```
def compare(f1, f2):
    is_same = True
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        if line1 != line2:
            is_same = False
    return is_same

files = request.FILES.getlist('a_bunch_of_posted_files') #get posted your files

same_files = True
for i in range (0,50):
    if i < 49:
        if not compare(files[i],files[i+1]:
            same_files = False
if(same_files)
    #then the files are all the same and you can just pick one to display 
    #or do whatever with
```

Comment: but how would i compare over 50 files? What I mean to say is, even if I compare a single file using this method, I'd need to repeat this for over 50 files. This works for a single file but as one increases the number of files to be compared, the number of methods would need to be increased too unless you have a better suggestion.

Comment: No, just add a loop or a recursive method which works through the comparisons of the files. Similarly, loop the file upload forms and post requests

Comment: that won't work since the names of the file I'm comparing the uploaded files to are different. A recursive loop won't help with different file names. Is there an implementation that you can show me to back your statement?

Comment: yes it will, it doesn't matter what the filenames are. give me a second to write one

Comment: There, that function shows you what I am talking about, its not very efficient, but you can just write a comparison function and then just run it across all of the files, and do whatever you want with the file once you have determined whether they are all equal or not

Comment: No I agreed with what you had to say about comparing the files but I think you have misunderstood me here. The user will upload a file answerfile.txt for a specific problem ( Question model foreign key in Answer model ) and then the answerfile.txt needs to be compared with the corresponding solution in the filefield of the Question model. How would I compare the corresponding solution of the filefield in the Question model with the uploaded file from the user. Maybe reference the id of the Question model's filefield?

Comment: Im not really sure what you are describing. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217849/discussion-between-arth-tyagi-and-figbar).