# Compare files ignoring trailing whitespaces in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, compare

Suppose I have two  ***LARGE***  text files ***file1.txt*** and ***file2.txt***  
content of ***file1.txt*** with trailing whitespace line

```
1 line1
2 line2
3
```

content of ***file2.txt***

```
1 line1
2 line2
```

where numbers refer to file line numbers. My function *compare(file1.txt, file2.txt)* must return *True* ignoring trailing whitespace lines. How can achieve this in *Python*?

Comment: read the data of both the files and compare it you may also use `str.strip()` to remove trailing whitespace.

Comment: @JacksonPro thanks for quick reply. Is it efficient for large files?

Comment: you may also checkout `filecmp` module:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-filecmp-cmp-method/#:~:text=cmp()%20method%20in%20Python,size%2C%20date%20modified%20etc.) also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007383/compare-two-different-files-line-by-line-in-python

Comment: how large we talking?

Comment: @Manakin 10^20 lines for example

Comment: @MamatkasymMamarasul for such a large file (how much is it in gig?) I would load it into a sql db and then do your analysis there. Python would struggle with such a large file, you could also look at `Dask` and `Pyspark`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to try.  No guarantees.

```
def file_test(file_name_1, file_name_2):
    line1 = ''
    line2 = ''
    with open(file_name_1) as file1, open(file_name_2) as file2:
        while True:
            line1 = file1.readline()
            line2 = file2.readline()
            # print(f"{line1!r} {line2!r}")
            if line1 == line2 == '':    # Both files end
                return True
            if line1 == '':
                last_line = line2
                long_file = file2
                break
            if line2 == '':
                last_line = line1
                long_file = file1
                break
            if line1 != line2:
                return False

        # print(f"at end {line1!r} {line2!r}")

        if last_line.strip() != '':
            return False

        # Check the rest of the long file for blank lines
        for line in long_file:
            print(f"long file {line!r}")
            if line.strip() != '':
                return False

    return True


print(file_test("file1.txt", "file2.txt"))
```