# Remove lines in one file, which are not present in another, by key

Tags: python

I have two text files, which look like this:

File1:

```
STR_ape,        1000
STR_banana,     1001
STR_orange,     1004
STR_strawberry, 1005
STR_gooseberry, 1007
...
```

File2:

```
1000="Some stringA"
1001="Some stringB"
1002="Some stringC"
1003="Some stringD"
1004="Some stringE"
1005="Some stringF"
1006="Some stringG"
1007="Some stringH"
...
```

So, some string ID:s in File1 are mapped to some strings in File2. What I want to do, is to remove all strings in File2, which are not present in File1. This means that File2 should look like this:

```
1000="Some stringA"
1001="Some stringB"
1004="Some stringE"
1005="Some stringF"
1007="Some stringH"
...
```

In other words,the strings whose numbers are not present in File1, should be removed. It is of course possible to achieve with counters and for loops, but I wonder if there is some built-in functions or a simple way of doing this in Python3.X?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two different files line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007383/compare-two-different-files-line-by-line-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the simplest and clearest way to accomplish this task:

First get all of the keys from file1, then get all of the matching lines from file2, and finally overwrite file2 with the matching lines.

```
file1 = 'file1.txt'
file2 = 'file2.txt'

keys = []
with open(file1, 'r') as fp:
    for l in fp.readlines():
        key = l.split(',')[1].strip()
        keys.append(key)
        
new_lines = []
with open(file2, 'r') as fp:
    for l in fp.readlines():
        key = l.split('=')[0].strip()
        if key in keys:
            new_lines.append(l)
            
with open(file2, 'w') as fp:
    fp.writelines(new_lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.x with `io` module is the present recommended way to read/write file, do a little looping to eliminate non-existing ids:

```py
s1 = \
"""
STR_ape,        1000
STR_banana,     1001
STR_orange,     1004
STR_strawberry, 1005
STR_gooseberry, 1007
"""

s2 = \
"""
1000="Some stringA"
1001="Some stringB"
1002="Some stringC"
1003="Some stringD"
1004="Some stringE"
1005="Some stringF"
1006="Some stringG"
1007="Some stringH"
"""

import io

# with io.open("File1","r") as f:
#     s1 = f.read().strip()
# with io.open("File2","r") as f:
#     s2 = f.read().strip()

s1 = s1.strip()    
s2 = s2.strip()

# Process File1
items = s1.split("\n")
ids   = []

for item in items:
    if len(item.strip())==0:
        continue # Skip blank lines, may be there

    id = item.split(",")[1].strip()
    ids.append(id)

print(ids)

# Process File2
items = s2.split("\n")
lines = []

for item in items:
    if len(item.strip())==0:
        continue

    id = item.split("=")[0].strip()

    if id in ids:
        lines.append(item)

text = "\n".join(lines)
print(text)

# Save text back to file, avoid writing to original File2 file
with io.open("File3","w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```